# Groovy collection sort with Closure and null safe check causes Exception

Tags: groovy

I have a statement like below in my code:

```groovy
otherParents.sort { -it.parent.lastUpdateDate.time }.each {
// ...
}
```

sometimes the `lastUpdateDate` will be null, and it result in exception.

How can I avoid it, I am completely new to groovy, I tried the question mark thing like

```
otherParents.sort { -it.parent?.lastUpdateDate?.time }.each {
// ...
}
```

but this is also not working

Comment: Are you sure that after adding the ?. operator it is failing due to lastUpdateTime being null. It could be some other reason too.

Comment: Yes, it fails in this case, because `negative()` function cannot be applied to a `null` value.

Comment: @SomBhattacharyya, yes the error message is same.

Answer (score 5):

There are two ways you can solve this problem. If you want to keep entries with `null` date, then you have to pass a closure that represents a comparator, something like this:

```
otherParents.sort { a,b -> b.parent.lastUpdatedDate?.time <=> a.parent.lastUpdatedDate?.time }.each {
    println it
}
```

It will sort entries in descending order and entries with `null` last updated date will be stored in the end of the list.

Alternatively, if you want to remove entries with `null` last updated date, then you can filter input list and use the same sort operation you used earlier:

```
otherParents.findAll { it.parent.lastUpdatedDate != null }.sort { -it.parent.lastUpdatedDate.time }.each {
    println it
}
```

The only difference is that the second example will sort only a list of entries that have non-null last updated date.

And below you can find an example with the output it produces:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat

def date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")

def otherParents = [
        [parent: [lastUpdatedDate: date.parse("2018-10-26T10:00:00")]],
        [parent: [lastUpdatedDate: date.parse("2018-10-26T10:00:01")]],
        [parent: [lastUpdatedDate: null]],
        [parent: [lastUpdatedDate: date.parse("2018-10-26T10:00:02")]],
        [parent: [lastUpdatedDate: date.parse("2018-10-26T10:00:03")]],
        [parent: [lastUpdatedDate: null]],
        [parent: [lastUpdatedDate: null]]
]

otherParents.sort { a,b -> b.parent.lastUpdatedDate?.time <=> a.parent.lastUpdatedDate?.time }.each {
    println it
}

println "----"

otherParents.findAll { it.parent.lastUpdatedDate != null }.sort { -it.parent.lastUpdatedDate.time }.each {
    println it
}
```

Output:

```
[parent:[lastUpdatedDate:Fri Oct 26 10:00:03 CEST 2018]]
[parent:[lastUpdatedDate:Fri Oct 26 10:00:02 CEST 2018]]
[parent:[lastUpdatedDate:Fri Oct 26 10:00:01 CEST 2018]]
[parent:[lastUpdatedDate:Fri Oct 26 10:00:00 CEST 2018]]
[parent:[lastUpdatedDate:null]]
[parent:[lastUpdatedDate:null]]
[parent:[lastUpdatedDate:null]]
----
[parent:[lastUpdatedDate:Fri Oct 26 10:00:03 CEST 2018]]
[parent:[lastUpdatedDate:Fri Oct 26 10:00:02 CEST 2018]]
[parent:[lastUpdatedDate:Fri Oct 26 10:00:01 CEST 2018]]
[parent:[lastUpdatedDate:Fri Oct 26 10:00:00 CEST 2018]]
```